# Postgresql cross-database references are not implemented

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create a database and then create a table in it. I wrote the query in an sql file to go with the postgres image using docker-compose.yml

When I to use docker-compose build and then docker-compose up I get an error

> "psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:18: ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "real_estate.public.estate"
>   postgres     | LINE 1: CREATE TABLE real_estate.public.estate ("

Here is my init.sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE "real_estate"
    WITH OWNER "postgres"
    ENCODING 'UTF8';
CREATE TABLE real_estate.public.estate (
    estate_title TEXT,
    estate_address TEXT,
    estate_area TEXT,
    estate_description TEXT,
    estate_price TEXT,
    estate_type TEXT,
    estate_tag TEXT,
    estate_date TEXT,
    estate_seller_name TEXT,
    estate_seller_address TEXT,
    estate_seller_phone TEXT,
    estate_seller_mobile TEXT,
    estate_seller_email TEXT
 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because you are not connected to the `real_estate` database.

I assume that you are connected to `postgres`, because that's what you typically do to run `CREATE DATABASE`.

You'll have to terminate the existing database connection and then start one to the newly created database. Only then you are allowed to create objects in the database.

It is a feature that different databases are strictly separated, and [any request to change that will be turned down](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BU5nMLwCe2XmH7QQPE98oU4cMmrgidsQzqRjdfqGXOhc%3D2s0g%40mail.gmail.com).

How to do this best depends on how you run the script. If you run it with `psql`, a simple `\c real_estate` would do.

Comment: oh it worked now,i added \c real_estate after create database and now the table is created in it thank you for the answer :)